# SAP BO REST service call doesn't return opendocument URL

Tags: rest, business-objects

In an application I am building to display BO reports through open document, BO server doesn't seem to respond with opendocument URL when performing a REST service call. Could you provide any clues as to why?

In dev environment a REST service call to `"http://server/biprws/infostore/<doc_id>"` with logon token in the HTTP header returns below response (last line you should see link to open document for that report)

Response

```
<entry xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
  <author>
    <name>Administrator</name>
    <uri>http://server/biprws/infostore/12</uri>
  </author>
  <id>tag:sap.com,2010:bip-rs/<ID></id>
  <title type="text">Blah Blah Blah</title>
  <updated>Updated_Date</updated>
  <link href="http://server/biprws/infostore/<doc_Id>" rel="up" />
  <link href="http://server/biprws/infostore/<doc_Id>/scheduleForms" rel="http://www.sap.com/rws/bip#schedule" title="Scheduling forms" />
  <content type="application/xml">
    <attrs xmlns="http://www.sap.com/rws/bip">
      <attr name="id" type="int32"><doc_Id></attr>
      <attr name="cuid" type="string"><doc_CUID></attr>
      <attr name="description" type="string">Blah Blah Blah</attr>
      <attr name="name" type="string">Blah Blah Blah</attr>
      <attr name="type" type="string">Webi</attr>
    </attrs>
  </content>
  <link href="http://SERVER/BOE/OpenDocument/opendoc/openDocument.jsp?sIDType=CUID&amp;iDocID=<doc_id>" rel="http://www.sap.com/rws/bip#opendocument" title="OpenDocument" />
</entry>
```

but when I make same call to QA environment, Open document URL is not being returned (last line in XML response). Is there any configuration I am missing?

Note: I replaced several links and text inside XML for safety purposes.

Comment: Did you update the <doc_Id> between the development and QA environment since doc_Id are not the same between different CMS ? We only guarantee that document keep the same cuid.

Comment: @ArnaudDevelay thanks for responding. Yes different cms system have been updated with different `<doc_Id>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved it by restarting the Apache web server where the SAP BO Server software hosts its Web Services and Also the SAP Bo Server software itself. This made the changes effective and applied the settings properly.